# php script to match given part of string in an array

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching

I have a string like `"123456-1234-001-N"` and array `$ids = array("123456-1234-002-N","123456-1234-001-S","4567789-4567-004-S","457896-14578-007-W")`

I would like to compare the string within the array and find out which remaining parts of string are not matching For e.g.:

- **case 1**: 123456, 1234 and N is present in array but in first case 001 is not matching, so error message is thrown
- **case 2**: 123456, 1234 and 001 is present in array and second case N is not matching , so error message is thrown.

  Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE 1:**
the script should match the entire string in array and display error message stating either third or fourth junk is not matching. E.g: we can use 123456 and 1234 of the string and see if 001 is matching or N is matching. Basically i need to know if third/fourth part of string is matching or not.

**UPDATE 2:**
I have chosen second method from the accepted answer!

Comment: "I tried with in_array() and preg_match() and failed." .. Could you update your question with your code, so that we are able to help you?

Comment: Are you trying to get exact matches (entire number must be matched), or just a part of the `$search` string?

Comment: @MaciejSz please find my edit , hopefully it is convincing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to your latest edit:

```
$search = "123456-1234-001-N";
$ids = array("123456-1234-002-N","123456-1234-001-S","4567789-4567-004-S","457896-14578-007-W");

$search_parts = explode('-', $search);

foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
    echo "Checking {$id}..." . PHP_EOL;
    $id_parts = explode('-', $id);
    $i = 0;
    $is_correct = true;
    foreach ( $search_parts as $part ) {
        $part_no = $i + 1;
        if ( $part != $id_parts[$i] ) {
            $is_correct = false;
            echo "  part number {$part_no} is incorrect (is: {$id_parts[$i]}, should be: {$part});" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if ( $is_correct ) {
        echo "  This is a correct id!" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

And the same thing (almost) done with `preg_match`:

```
$search = "123456-1234-001-N";

$search_pattern = '/^([0-9]*)\\-([0-9]*)\\-([0-9]*)\\-([A-Z]*)$/';
$ids = array("123456-1234-002-N","123456-1234-001-S","4567789-4567-004-S","457896-14578-007-W");

$search_parts = explode('-', $search);
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
    $res = preg_match($search_pattern, $id, $matches);
    if ( ! $res ) {
        throw new Exception("The id {$id} is in invalid format");
    }
    $diff = array_diff($search_parts, $matches);
    printDiffMessage($diff);
    echo PHP_EOL . "----" . PHP_EOL;
}

function printDiffMessage(array $diff)
{
    foreach ( $diff as $key => $value ) {
        $pos = $key + 1;
        echo "Keys differ at position {$pos}. ";
    }
}
```

**Previous (kept for reference):**

Try this code:

```
$ids = array("123456-1234-002-N","123456-1234-001-S","4567789-4567-004-S","457896-14578-007-W");

$search = '123456-1234-001-N';

foreach ( $ids as $single_id ) {
    $match = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( str_split($search) as $chr ) {
        if ( $single_id[$i] != $chr ) {
            break;
        }
        $match .= $chr;
        $i++;
    }
    var_dump($match);
}
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

To your edit: seems like `in_array` is what you need.

```
if ( in_array($search, $ids) ) {
    echo "Found it";
}
else {
    echo "Error message";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for attempt , please see the updated question... let me know if still not clear

Comment: wow this is almost what i wanted, but, one other thing, the match should continue only if first and second part matches, i,e if 123456 and 1234 then only it should proceed to validate the third and fourth part, hope understood?

Comment: You can achieve this (only with the first solution) by adding `break;` after `$i >= 1` within the `if ( $part != $id_parts[$i] )` condition. By in my opinion the solution using `preg_match` is more robust and clean.

Comment: Actually you can also mute the error message in the `preg_match` solution conditionally like this: `if ( array_key_exists(0, $diff) || array_key_exists(1, $diff) ) { /** don't show the error message *// }`

Comment: I need to get this using second method itself, because i need to throw error message to user as which part is not matching... i would try to edit the code and see if i can get it, please do update if you can achieve it. thanks a lot again!

Comment: It is simple enough, you can do it. I already gave you everything that you need.

Comment: yes! their u go.. accepted ur answer. Appreciate it again! :)